# Как отправлять значение формы type="checkbox" в обработчик

Tags: checkbox, html, form

Если галочка поставлена - в обработчик летит 1, если нет, то 0. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зря минусуют, хороший вопрос

Comment: @alexlz чем же он хорош, позвольте полюбопытствовать? Человек даже не смог его адекватно сформулировать, уж не говоря о том, что то,о чем он спрашивает - самые азы, и такое просто стыдно спрашивать

Comment: @DreamChild я многих вопросов здесь не понимаю, но тут понял только "заранее спасибо". Это **очень** хороший вопрос. Если мне объяснят, чего хочет ТС, то вопрос потеряет всё своё очарование.

Comment: Ответ невероятно интересен, а именно: ничего для это не надо делать, так формы и отправляются.

Comment: @alexlz, ну если это вы в саркастическом смысле)
Кстати, что удивительно - как его умудрились заминусовать до -37?))

Comment: Ответ @Construct мне напомнил один старый анекдот: "Но тут пришёл поручик Ржевский и всё опошлил"

Comment: @alexlz, простите :(

Comment: @Construct Вам предо мной извиняться не за что. Просто удивляет, что большинство вопросов строится по принципу "догадайся, что мне надо, и подскажи как это сделать". Когда пытаешься уточнить проблему, частенько обижаются.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пропишите чекбоксу атрибут `value="1"`, вот и в обработчик передастся 1.

Comment: а если галочка не поставлена, и checked не стоит, то как 0 отправлять?

Comment: когда чекбокс неактивен, то он вообще ничего не отошлет!

Comment: @Кирилл Glaz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @DreamChild, просто никто свои варианты не выдвигает, вот выходит это исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: @RollOver если нет правильных ответов, плохой ответ от этого правильным все равно не станет. А своих никто не выдвигает потому что вопрос очень уж..хм..бестолковый. На такие отвечать-то даже стыдно